# Get correct long value from parsed Date (Timezone issue)

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I'm trying to parse a date from a String and get the long value. The long value will be later sent to an SQL query.

here's my code:

```
String dayDate = "28-02-2013";            
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date day = new Date();
try {
    day = sdf.parse(dayDate);
} catch (ParseException pe) {
    pe.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("day : "+day.toString()+ "  long : " + day.getTime());
```

which gives the following output:

```
day : Thu Feb 28 00:00:00 EET 2013  long : 1362002400000
```

which is correct but not what I want since the long value results in Wed, 27 Feb 2013 22:00:00 GMT (http://www.epochconverter.com/) (I'm in a GMT+2 timezone). And i need to send to correct long value to sql.

Is there anyway to work around this without using external libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SimpleDateFormat is locale-aware, meaning the date it parses is in your timezone. Midnight 28 Feb in GMT+2 is actually 10pm 27 Feb in GMT, the long value 1362002400000. I would add this to get the parsing right (would't bother using Calendar):

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
```

Again, when you print this date it uses SimpleDateFormat and that's why you can see EET in the output.

Passing this to database is a different story though once you get this right.

Comment: That was simple :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateFormat.setCalendar(Calendar cal)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setCalendar%28java.util.Calendar%29) to set a Calendar with GMT as its timezone, or use [`DateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone zone)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) with the GMT TimeZone. That will ensure that the resulting Date will be 00:00:00 in GMT instead of in EET.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a timezone specifier to your string you can force java to use GMT for the conversion:

```
String dayDate = "28-02-2013";            
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy z"); // z is a timezone specifier
Date day = new Date();
try {
    day = sdf.parse(dayDate + " GMT"); // Use GMT timezone.
} catch (ParseException pe) {
    pe.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("day : "+day.toString()+ "  long : " + day.getTime());
```

Comment: I like your approach, but i'm gonna go with houman001's answer. Thanks!

Comment: Good choice. His solution is a more elegant way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting between text and internal  (`Date`) representations of dates and times without explicitly stating the time-zone. [That never goes well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6858453/545127).

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Use your timezone String:

[TimeZones](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/)